# Disable 4th title-bar button (menu) on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: gnome, window, menu, titlebar, window-buttons

I have just now installed Ubuntu and i am seeing 4 title bar buttons on some windows (menu, min, max, close)

I would really like to get rid of the menu button. Possible?

I'm using standard Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Terminal and run the following command

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences button-layout :minimize,maximize,close
```